# Searching all downloaded files in a file list

Tags: command-line, xargs

I've downloaded some files. I want to find out whether these file names are present in file.txt one by one. I've tried following command but not successful. I want to find out using `xargs`.

`ls | xargs grep file.txt`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm not sure what exactly means your *"one by one"* but here is

Short **`ls`** + **`grep`** approach:

```
ls -1 | grep -wf - file.txt
```

---

- `-1` - `ls` option, lists one file per line
- `-f file` - `grep` option, obtains patterns from `file`(or STDIN in case of passing `-` argument), one per line

---

The same could be written as:

```
grep -wf <(ls -1) file.txt
```